# Standard UK Visit Visa - Who should I address the cover letter to?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

For an Indian national applying for a standard visit visa to the UK in Bangalore, who should the cover letter be addressed to?

Comment: "To whom it may concern"?

Comment: Are you offering some specific information in you cover letter ? If not it is a waste of paper and ink. Think about the trees that have to be sacrificed for this waste.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific guidance on this that I'm aware of.

In the past, I've addressed the letter to the appropriate High Commission, the salutation being "Dear Entry Clearance Officer". As Moo has suggested in the comments, "To whom it may concern" is also an option.

Whichever form of address you choose, it's quite unlikely to materially affect your application; it's the content of the letter that really matters.